# R: How can I make a new Variable with numbers of order (by date) for every level (for reshaping).)

Tags: r, reshape

I´m new to R and I have to deal with a large data set. I googled a lot but I just can´t find the way to do what i need (although it sounds like an easy thing to do).

What I want to do is reshape my data in a wide form. To do it in the way that I want, I need a new variable with numbers of order by dates for every factor (that will start with one for each new factor).

Now, this is a small example of what I have:

```
ID<-c("A","A","A","B","B","C","D","D","D","D")

Date<-c("01-01-2014", "05-01-2014", "06-01-2014",
        "01-01-2014", "12-01-2014", "25-01-2014", 
        "06-01-2014", "12-01-2014", "25-01-2014", 
        "26-01-2014")

Value<-c(2.5, 3.4, 2.5, 305.66, 300.00, 55.01,
        205.32, 99.99, 210.25, 105.125)

mydata<-data.frame(ID, Date, Value)
mydata

ID       Date   Value
1   A 01-01-2014   2.500
2   A 05-01-2014   3.400
3   A 06-01-2014   2.500
4   B 01-01-2014 305.660
5   B 12-01-2014 300.000
6   C 25-01-2014  55.010
7   D 06-01-2014 205.320
8   D 12-01-2014  99.990
9   D 25-01-2014 210.250
10  D 26-01-2014 105.125
```

(Data set is sorted first by ID factor, than by date for each factor.)

And this is what I need: new variable called "Order".

```
   ID       Date   Value Order
1   A 01-01-2014   2.500     1
2   A 05-01-2014   3.400     2
3   A 06-01-2014   2.500     3
4   B 01-01-2014 305.660     1
5   B 12-01-2014 300.000     2
6   C 25-01-2014  55.010     1
7   D 06-01-2014 205.320     1
8   D 12-01-2014  99.990     2
9   D 25-01-2014 210.250     3
10  D 26-01-2014 105.125     4
```

The end goal is to reshape data based on the variable "Order" like this:

```
library(reshape)
goal<-reshape(mydata2, 
              idvar="ID",
              timevar="Order",
              direction="wide")
goal

   ID     Date.1  Value.1     Date.2  Value.2     Date.3  Value.3     Date.4  Value.4
1  A  01-01-2014    2.50  05-01-2014    3.40  06-01-2014    2.50        <NA>      NA
4  B  01-01-2014  305.66  12-01-2014  300.00        <NA>       NA       <NA>      NA
6  C  25-01-2014   55.01        <NA>      NA        <NA>       NA       <NA>      NA
7  D  06-01-2014  205.32  12-01-2014   99.99  25-01-2014   210.25   26-01-2014 105.125
```

Or is there another way to reshape data like this without the "Order" Variable?

Comment: Using `ave` from `base R` you can get the `Order` column `mydata2 <- transform(mydata, Order=ave(seq_along(ID), ID, FUN=seq_along))` and then use `reshape`

Comment: This works great! Tnx!

Answer (score 3):

This is precisely what the `getanID` function in my "splitstackshape" package is for:

```
> library(splitstackshape)
> getanID(mydata, "ID")
    ID       Date   Value .id
 1:  A 01-01-2014   2.500   1
 2:  A 05-01-2014   3.400   2
 3:  A 06-01-2014   2.500   3
 4:  B 01-01-2014 305.660   1
 5:  B 12-01-2014 300.000   2
 6:  C 25-01-2014  55.010   1
 7:  D 06-01-2014 205.320   1
 8:  D 12-01-2014  99.990   2
 9:  D 25-01-2014 210.250   3
10:  D 26-01-2014 105.125   4
```

Alternatively, you can explore the development version of "data.table" which reimplements `dcast` in a very flexible way that will allow you to do this transformation without needing to generate a "time" variable.

Comment: A complete solution will be probably something like `dcast(getanID(mydata, "ID"), ID ~ .id,  value.var = c("Date", "Value"))`

Comment: This works for my small example, but when I apply "getanID" funktion on my data set with 70 000 observations it crashes my R session down. Since the code from a comment above works for me, you don´t need to search for an answer/solution, unless you want to do it for possibility that someone else is going to have the same problem.

Comment: @Peky84, that's surprising to me since `getanID` is basically `data[, `:=`(.id, sequence(.N)), by = id.vars]` in "data.table", so should be able to handle 70K without a problem.

Comment: @Ananda Matho, well I tryed it several times, the same thing happend like 10 times and only once I got the message: Error in unlist(lapply(nvec, seq_len)) : bytecode version is too old - .

Comment: @Peky84, what version of "data.table" and "splitstackshape" are you using? Can you generate some simulated data that recreates the problem and post it as an issue on Github for "splitstackshape"? I'd like to look into this more.

Comment: @Ananda Matho, "data.table": 1.9.4., "splitstackshape" : 1.4.2. I just updated both of them and the session was aborted again. If the version were a problem, it would not work with the small example either, or? What do you mean by generate simulated data? I thought that was my small example :) I´m not sure how to simulate example that would recreate the same error since I don´t know what is causing it.

Comment: @Ananda Matho, I took the first 80 observations and tryed the same on the "cuted" version of my data set and the code works just fine.

Comment: @Peky84, That error is strange. What you've shown there is the code for `sequence`.... If you were to do `summary` or `table` on the grouping column, is there anything strange in there? Any `NA` values perhaps?